# Data on present and future electricity demand profiles in the UK

Tags: data-request, energy

I am looking for typical electricity demand profiles with hourly granularity for domestic, commercial, and industrial sectors in the UK in the present and, if possible, in the future.

Could you point me to relevant sources?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently worked with the European portal for electricity transparency https://transparency.entsoe.eu/.

Probably you can find some answers over there. There is an [API](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/web%20api/Guide.html) which needs a simple registration but it's free and produces time series in XML format.

It may take some time to get an overview of the different categories but I could imagine e.g. [Total Load Forecast - Year Ahead](https://transparency.entsoe.eu/content/static_content/Static%20content/web%20api/Guide.html#_year_ahead_total_load_forecast_6_1_e) to suit your needs.

Comment: Hello Tareq, Which software do you use to read the xml file?

Comment: I use Java with JAXB API to convert XML to Java classes and put required information into CSV files.

Comment: @Samy That is too broad a question, you should say what you want to do with the XML files. That also shows that [your question does not contain enough information](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like), please edit it. Maybe [this helps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+xml+to+csv) as well.

Comment: Hi Jan, I can't edit the comment, but tareq gave me a good answer. I have never worked with xml data before I did not really know what to ask specifically.

Comment: @tareq I need to have data that is typical for domestic, commercial and industrial users as stated in the questions. It seems that ENTSOE deals with aggregate country data. Are you sure that I can get what I need from there?

Comment: @SamyGeronymos The API exposes data at country and so-called bidding zone level (which is mostly part of a country). According to my understanding, the data is more of aggregated data per such an area and might not suit your user profiles. Yet I am not expert at the domain side of the data, it is more about retrieving the data for me. At least they support the hourly resolution you were looking for, for some of the variables.